# how to run apache NifiModule on Azure IoT edge device?

Tags: apache-nifi, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I deployed apache nifi module on azure iot edge device with following desired properties:

```
{
    "certificatefile": "azure-iot-test-only.root.ca.cert.pem",
    "flowversion": "1.1",
    "accountname": "",
    "accountkey": "",
    "containername": ""
}
```

I got following error while running the module:
[image]

I placed root ca certificate and flow file on edge device in /config folder.

Can anyone please suggest the solution? It failed to execute following command

```
[ERROR] Error loading certificate: Command failed: keytool -import -noprompt -alias iot-edge -file /config/azure-iot-test-only.root.ca.cert.pem -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that the following service have read permissions for the directories holding the certificates and keys:

- The private key file should be owned by the **aziotks** group.
- The certificate files should be owned by the **aziotcs** group

Ref: [Configure IoT Edge with the new certificates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-manage-device-certificates?view=iotedge-2020-11&tabs=linux#configure-iot-edge-with-the-new-certificates)

Comment: Thank you so much, It is working now !!! I changed the permissions for root CA certificate and set path correctly. Additionally changed the port in deployment file.